# How can I pass parameters using the "Clicked"-Method on a button in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have recently started using .Net MAUI. however, I have now encountered a problem with which I could not find any help on the internet. I want when I click a button that a defined click function is called. However, I can't pass a parameter to the "Clicked" attribute. How do I do that?

I tried to solve my problem with the help of various posts in different online forums, but none of these posts helped and so I am creating my own.

My code so far:

XAML:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="50" Margin="50">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Stroke="Transparent"
                    StrokeThickness="3"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 30,30,30,30"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0">
                <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onStudentSelected"/> <!-- Here i want to give a param -->
                </Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="250">
                    <Border Stroke="#21B1FF"
                    StrokeThickness="3"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15, 15, 15"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Margin="10">
                        <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="240">
                            <Label FontSize="25" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Max Muster" Padding="10"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Stroke="#21B1FF"
                    StrokeThickness="3"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15, 15, 15"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="White">
                        <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="240">
                            <Label Margin="5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Newest Grade: 5.8" Padding="10"/>
                            <Label Margin="5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Average: 4.5" Padding="10"/>
                            <Label Margin="5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Best Subject: Math" Padding="10"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Border>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

C#:

```
private async void onStudentSelected(object sender, EventArgs e, int id)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("StudentDetail" + id);
    }
```

Am grateful for any help :)

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far.  This gives us some context and helps us help you better.  For what it's worth, binding to a command property is preferable to hooking an event on a button.

Comment: Please show some code (as text!) instead of explaining what your code does. You may also want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot pass a parameter to an event handler via XAML. That's what `Command` and `CommandParameter` are for.

Comment: Sorry guys, i tried my best :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get the `id` from the `BindingContext`

```
private async void onStudentSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // assuming your Model class is "Student"
        var border = (Border)sender;
        var item = (Student)border.BindingContext;
        var id = item.Id;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("StudentDetail" + id);
    }
```

alternately (and more aligned with MVVM) you can use [Command and CommandParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: You should fix up the signature, because the `id` argument is not part of the event handler signature.

Comment: thanks, didn't even notice that when I copied it from his post

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason said, you can use the [Command and CommandParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding?view=net-maui-7.0#using-command-parameters).

Here is the demo for you to refer to.

```
 <TextCell Text="Customimze an Entry"
           Detail="Select text on focus"
           Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
           CommandParameter="{x:Type views:CustomizeEntryPage}" />
```

Code behind:

```
 public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>(
            async (Type pageType) =>
            {
                Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            });

        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: This will work, but it will not work with MVVM in case that a ViewModel is already set as the BindingContext

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandParameter with the tapped event

```
<Border.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="onStudentSelected"/>
 </Border.GestureRecognizers>
```

Code Behind:

```
private async void onStudentSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var student = (e.Parameter) as Student;
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("StudentDetail" + student.id);
}
```